# Disable signature probing for repositories in update-manager

Tags: apt, update-manager, gnupg

Update-manager brought up an update today, but refused to install it.

> "This action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated package sources." *(transliterated error message, couldn't locate English original)*

That's because of a package from a custom old/flat Debian-style repository, which no gpg keys are available for (and I won't bug the maintainer about it). Also it was working perfectly fine with update-manager before. So I assume there was a recent change.

Is there are an `apt.conf` setting or an `update-manager` configuration ability to disable that check? Since it's probably not possible for a single repository, I'd rather disable *all* checks now. (Typical security outcome for nonsensical restrictions.)

I've worked around the issue now with a manual `apt-get upgrade` - where the signature-less repository is still a normal warning, not a fatal error. But I would prefer to have a user-friendly solution to this, and again use the update-manager update button when it pops up next time.

---

Still unresolved. I've found out about the [`apt-get --allow-unauthenticated` option](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecureApt) meanwhile. But that doesn't help me for update-manager.

```
 APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated "true";
```

Adding this [`apt.conf` setting](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=28881) also didn't alter the behaviour.